# Principal Component Analysis - three classes mixed on three seperated groups

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, dataset, pca

I have a Dataset with 3 labels and 27 features. I was trying to use the PCA on it and reduce the dimensions to 2. The results are a bit confusing. Honestly, I didn't expect too good results, but I got the first picture and I was very surprised. [image]

Since I have three labels, I thought that I got my three classes pretty clear. However, when I apply the colors, I get the following picture:
[image]

I am a bit wondered about the fact that the three classes are totally mixed on three clearly seperated groups. I also tried it in 3D an the results looks exactly the same.
Is there any error in my code or does anyone know a reason why this could happen?

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import (StandardScaler, MaxAbsScaler, RobustScaler, 
Normalizer, QuantileTransformer, PowerTransformer, MinMaxScaler)
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np


Dataset = pd.read_csv("...", header=0)
feature_spalten = ['...']
x = Dataset[feature_spalten]
y = Dataset.Classifier
sc = StandardScaler()
x = sc.fit_transform(x)

p = PCA()
p.fit(x)

x_transformed = p.transform(x)

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x_transformed[:, 0], x_transformed[:, 1])

plt.figure()
for label in y.unique():
    x_transformed_filtered = x_transformed[y == label, :]
    plt.scatter(x_transformed_filtered[:, 0], x_transformed_filtered[:, 1], 
                label=label, s = 25)
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you pls try to visualize the 3D dimension version of the PCA.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question.

Answer (score 2):

This is suggestive that your data is clustered in high dimensional space, with each cluster comprised of instances with an assortment of the labels.

The objective of PCA is to find a lower-dimensional projection that preserves the variance of the data. The following hypothetical example shows how linearly separable two-dimensional data (with three clusters) can be projected to one dimension, with the clusters in the projection not corresponding to labels (red versus blue).

[image: 2D to 1D PCA projection]